# Как изменить разрешение экрана QEMU?

Tags: linux, экран, qemu

Я хочу изменить разрешение экрана QEMU. Все бы ничего, но я из запускаемой системы не смогу это настроить (по крайней мере, не знаю, как это сделать), ядро и ramdisk беру с хоста, т е GRUB у меня, считай, нету. Экран я могу настроить только через QEMU. Как поменять разрешение? Да, я могу сделать `Ctrl+Alt+F`, но буквы в консоли слишком крупные...

Опции QEMU:

```
 ~/linux # qemu-system-x86_64 -m 1G -k en -kernel linux-5.15.56/arch/x86_64/boot/bzImage -smp cpus=2 -initrd initrd.gz -drive if=virtio,file=ext4.img -vga virtio
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо было в опции ядра прописать

```
vga=ask
```

И руками выбирать разрешение...